# stream audio from S3 with Angular and Springboot without sharing bucket URL

Tags: angular, spring-boot, amazon-s3, audio-streaming

My objective is to create an application that should allow to stream audio from S3 buckets.
My backend is actually returning a list of titles to stream. In my controller I have a basic call:

```
@GetMapping(
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<Flux<AudioResponseDto>> getPlaylist() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(this.audioService.getPlaylist(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

In my service:

```
@Override
public Flux<AudioResponseDto> getPlaylist() {
    return audioRepository.findAll().map(AudioUtils::audioEntityToAudioResponseDto);
}
```

As a matter of fact my code is working and i'm returning AudioResponseDto but it's rather dirty: anyone can download the file because the URL link is visible
Here is my model response object:

```
public class AudioResponseDto {
    private String id;
    private String title;
    private String artist;
    private String album;
    private int year;
    private byte[] albumImage;
    private int length;
    private String streamUrl;
}
```

My streamUrl is a link to a file from S3 bucket and looks like this:

`https://custom-storage-audio.s3.eu-west-3.amazonaws.com/{folderId]/my+file.mp3`

My front app is running on angular. My work is highly inspired from Shibaji Debnath tutorial that allowed me to have a first approach on audio streaming.
I call my springboot app and retrieve a playlist. I implemented a service to call my API:

```
getFiles(): Observable<AudioStream[]> {
  return this.http.get<AudioStream[]>("http://localhost:8080/audio/tracks")
}
```

My AudioStream model is based on the AudioResponseDto object:

```
export interface AudioStream {
  id: string;
  title: string;
  artist: string;
  album: string;
  year: number;
  albumImage: any[];
  length: number;
  streamUrl: string;
}
```

To play a title, a method is called:

```
openFile(file: AudioStream, index: number) {
  this.currentFile = { index, file };
  this.audioService.stop();
  this.playStream(file.streamUrl);
}

playStream(url: string) {
  this.audioService.playStream(url).subscribe( (events: any) => {
    if(events.type == 'ended'){
      if(!this.isLastPlaying()){
        this.next();
      }else{
        this.openFile(this.files[0], 0);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

From my service:

```
playStream(url: string) {
  return this.streamObservable(url).pipe(takeUntil(this.stop$));
}
```

I do have security concerns:

1. I would like to make the file readable but not available for download for guests
2. Make the title available for download in specific conditions
3. I would like to have an url each time a title is listened

Ideally, my AudioResponse should not contain web url that make the track available for download, I would like to stream from S3 without sharing URL by passing bytes array, without downloading possibility, and without giving the link to the bucket.

I do think I should create a route that retrieve the file from S3 in springboot and return a content to stream. I will also have the same issue concerning videos :)

I hope that I make myself clear enough.
Thanks

Comment: did you find an answer?